# How can i paste columns from separate files using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, list, unix, command

I want to merge different lists with delimiter "-".

first list has 2 words

```
  $ cat first
    one
    who
```

second list has 10000 words

```
$ cat second
languages
more
simple
advanced
home
expert
......
......
test
nope
```

i want two list merge, same ...

```
$cat merge-list
one-languages
one-more
....
....
who-more
....
who-test
who-nope
....
```

Comment: What did you try already to solve your problem? Add some of the relevant code to debug into your question.

Answer (score 0):

<del>[Paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)) should do the trick.</del>

> paste is a Unix command line utility which is used to join files horizontally (parallel merging) by outputting lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines of each file specified, separated by tabs, to the standard output.

Example

```
paste -d - file1 file2
```

EDIT:

I just saw that your two files have different length. Unfortunately paste is not 
helping with these kinds of problems. But you could of course use something like this:

```
for i in `cat file1`; do 
    for j in `cat file2`; do 
        echo $i-$j
    done
done
```

Comment: thank you for bash script but i want to command? is it possible? Only *nix commands? awk,sed,cut,paste..?